# Are API credentials for authorization code flow limited to client secrets and service accounts to certificates

Tags: google-oauth, client, credentials, client-certificates

For OAuth2 credentials, I have been used to MSFT supporting both *client secrets* and *X.509 certificates* for both authorization_code and client_credentials grant flows. Google appear to have restricted authorization_code to client secrets and client_credentials (i.e. service accounts) to certificates.
Are there options on the API portal I have missed?
Or do 'OAuth 2.0 Client IDs' handle both authorization_code and client_credentials grant flows, with service accounts supporting daemon flows other than client_credentials?